# Mapa de google en HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy armando un template de HTML y en él quiero agregar el mapa de google, revisando requiero una API key de google.

La pregunta es: voy a vender ese template ¿hay alguna manera de mostrar el mapa sin usar mi API KEY personal (sin usar el metodo de iframe)?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder trabajar con Google Maps desde una aplicación o página web, necesitas habilitar las APIS necesarias (Rutas, Sitios, Geolocalización, etc) y necesitas SÍ o SÍ tener una cuenta de Google con las Apis necesarias para ello.
Mi consejo, es que crees una cuenta de Google específica para este proyecto (es gratis) ya que si piensas entregar el código... No creo que puedas decirles "tienen que crear una cuenta y habilitar los APIS"